# Is there a way to create a pandas dataframe whose rows are integers which increase until a certain value is reached in each row?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

For example, suppose I had the array of integers [5, 3, 7, 6, 4]. I'm hoping to find an efficient way to create a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

This should be such that the first row in the dataframe contains the numbers 1 to 5, the second should contain the numbers 1 to 3, and so on.

Is there a way to achieve this without looping?

Comment: how are the array and the dataframe related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy and masked arrays for performance:

```
a = [5, 3, 7, 6, 4]

n = np.repeat(np.arange(1, max(a)+1)[None, :], len(a), axis=0)
m = n > np.array(a)[:, None]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ma.array(n, mask=m))
```

where we first form `n` that is `1..max(a)` repeated by length of `a` and then find `m` that masks the appropriate places for `np.NaN`. Then, masked array is passed to the frame constructor,

to get

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

timings:

For the given setup:

```
a = [5, 3, 7, 6, 4]

# @Vishnudev's solution
%timeit pd.DataFrame(range(1, x+1) for x in a)

553 µs ± 25.2 µs per loop

# @Tom Mclean's solution (a bit modified for generalization)
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(1, max(a)+1))]*len(a))
df[df.ge(a, axis=0)] = np.nan

2.14 ms ± 43.9 µs per loop

# This solution
%%timeit
n = np.repeat(np.arange(1, max(a)+1)[None, :], len(a), axis=0)
m = n > np.array(a)[:, None]
pd.DataFrame(np.ma.array(n, mask=m))

139 µs ± 2.22 µs per loop
```

For a large array:

```
a = np.random.randint(3, 10_000, size=5_000)

# @Vishnudev solution
%timeit pd.DataFrame(range(1, x+1) for x in a)

8.12 s ± 76 ms per loop

# @Tom Mclean's solution (a bit modified for generalization)
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(1, max(a)+1))]*len(a))
df[df.ge(a, axis=0)] = np.nan

15 s ± 199 ms per loop

# This solution
%%timeit
n = np.repeat(np.arange(1, max(a)+1)[None, :], len(a), axis=0)
m = n > np.array(a)[:, None]
pd.DataFrame(np.ma.array(n, mask=m))

583 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know whether there is a way to change the increments used in each row too? For example, if I also had the array `b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]` could this code be modified so that the first, second, and fifth rows increase in steps of 1, the third increases in steps of 2, and the fourth increases in steps of 3? I've tried passing the array `b` as a third argument to `np.arange`, but this does not work.

Comment: @J.Chapman So in that example, third will increase in steps of 2 but the end result is `[1, 3, 5, 7]` or `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]`? i.e., is 7 interpreted as the last entry or the number of entries?

Comment: Note to readers: None in slicing is the same as np.newaxis

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın So that the result would be [1, 3, 5, 7]

Comment: @J.Chapman Then you can use Vishnudev's solution modified `pd.DataFrame(range(1, a_i+1, b_i) for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b))` because above solution is not easily adapted to that issue (maybe not possible).

Answer (score 4):

A simple one-liner with `range` function

```
pd.DataFrame(range(1, x+1) for x in [5, 3, 7, 6, 4])
```

Output

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I tried this on my machine and got 0.00165s per loop, vs my method and got 0.000992s per loop, but I would have guessed that yours would be faster. However I didnt test the performance with different size dataframes

Comment: What about the second code? It would be the fastest @TomMcLean

Comment: That code achieved 0.000571s per loop, so slightly better than my one, I would guess that the performance would be even better with a larger df though

Comment: It will scale for larger data too @TomMcLean. Since there is no replacement happening or `apply` function.

Comment: readable but not sure about the scaling and fastest-ness. Added some timings in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

setting up a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]*5)
```

filtering the maximum values row wise:

```
max_row_val = [5, 3, 7, 6, 4]
df.ge(max_row_val, axis=0)

       0      1      2      3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False  False  False   True   True
1  False  False  False   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False   True
4  False  False  False  False   True   True   True
```

And just set the df to nan at `True`

```
df[df.ge(max_row_val, axis=0)] = np.nan
   0  1  2    3    4    5    6
0  1  2  3  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
1  1  2  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1  2  3  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
3  1  2  3  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN
4  1  2  3  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This achieved 0.0003582255399999667s per loop on my machine for this size df.

Comment: What is `max_row_val`? Was adding timings but couldn't include yours due to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the *.apply()* method.
Though, if you need to do this on a big dataframe, the performance will be really bad.
[solution with apply methode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShONB.png)

Comment: You do not need to loop over the dataframe to solve this problem

Comment: Yup, pretty much what i was meaning when i said that performance would be really bad on a big dataframe. The intent of my comment was just to show another way of doing, though we agree that this is by far a worse solution.