# Is it possible to use numpy's arange function to create an array of dates increasing with intervals of 1 year?

Tags: python, numpy, timedelta

To use `numpy.arange` to create an array of dates which increase in 1 day intervals is straightforward and can be achieved using the code

```
np.arange(datetime(1985,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1), relativedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime)
```

However, I require an array of dates which increase in 1 year intervals. To do this, I cannot use

```
np.arange(datetime(1985,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1), relativedelta(days=365)).astype(datetime)
```

since this does not account for leap years and I need the day and month of my dates to remain the same at all terms.

Is there a way to achieve this using np.arange?

I wish to use numpy.arrange since I am hoping to use @Mustafa Aydın's answer to my earlier question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68032151/10346788) but with dates rather than with integers.

Answer (score 1):

Specify only the year and the month in the `datetime64` , and set the interval as 1 year . For example ,to generate all dates of March 10 , from 1985 to 2015

```
np.arange(np.datetime64("1985-03"), np.datetime64("2015-03"),np.timedelta64(1,"Y")) +np.timedelta64("9","D")

array(['1985-03-10', '1986-03-10', '1987-03-10', '1988-03-10',
       '1989-03-10', '1990-03-10', '1991-03-10', '1992-03-10',
       '1993-03-10', '1994-03-10', '1995-03-10', '1996-03-10',
       '1997-03-10', '1998-03-10', '1999-03-10', '2000-03-10',
       '2001-03-10', '2002-03-10', '2003-03-10', '2004-03-10',
       '2005-03-10', '2006-03-10', '2007-03-10', '2008-03-10',
       '2009-03-10', '2010-03-10', '2011-03-10', '2012-03-10',
       '2013-03-10', '2014-03-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
np.array([datetime(i,7,1) for i in range(1985,2015+1)])
```

EDIT: or just as a normal list - in case it does not have to be a numpy array:

```
[datetime(i,7,1) for i in range(1985,2015+1)]
```